# Need to print the lines that matches regex for both themselves and neighboring lanes

Tags: awk

I have a problem and thus i ask :)
i have input... something like this

```
48 06-Jul-16 00:04:26.850000, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:29.200000, 0.35
 60 06-Jul-16 00:04:29.250000, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:32.190476, 0.35
 11 06-Jul-16 00:04:32.238095, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:32.761905, 0.35
 20 06-Jul-16 00:04:32.809524, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:33.800000, 0.35
 14 06-Jul-16 00:04:33.850000, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:34.550000, 0.35
  4 06-Jul-16 00:04:34.600000, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:34.800000, 0.35
 28 06-Jul-16 00:04:34.850000, 0.3
  2 06-Jul-16 00:04:36.238095, 0.35
 12 06-Jul-16 00:04:36.333333, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:36.904762, 0.35
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:36.952381, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:37.000000, 0.35
 22 06-Jul-16 00:04:37.050000, 0.3
  2 06-Jul-16 00:04:38.150000, 0.35
 10 06-Jul-16 00:04:38.250000, 0.3
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:38.750000, 0.35
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:38.800000, 0.3
```

and I need an output where the first column is 1, it's previous line and next line 1st columns must be more than 12 and fourth columns both bigger or both lower than current rows 4th column, like this

```
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:29.200000, 0.35
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:33.800000, 0.35
```

I tried to play with awk a bit but to no vain

`awk '($1=1) && NR+1($1>12) && NR-1($1>12){print $0}'`

And I understand that it is totally wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you do with the first and last lines - never print them?

Comment: this is just some part of the whole file, and I don't need the first and last parts of it

Comment: @Tigran : Please rephrase `it's previous line and next line must be more than 12 and fourth columns both bigger or both lower,`

Comment: @sjsam : it's previous line and next line 1st columns must be more than 12 and fourth columns both bigger or both lower than current rows 4th column,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[NR] = $0; next }
{ split(a[FNR-1],p); split(a[FNR+1],n) }
(FNR > 1) && ($1 == 1) && (p[1] > 12) && (n[1] > 12) &&
    ( ( (p[4] > $4) && (n[4] > $4) ) ||
      ( (p[4] < $4) && (n[4] < $4) ) )

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:29.200000, 0.35
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:33.800000, 0.35
```

or if you prefer it in one pass at the expense of a little more complexity:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ split(prev,p); split(curr,c); split($0,n) }
(NR > 2) && (c[1] == 1) && (p[1] > 12) && (n[1] > 12) &&
    ( ( (p[4] > c[4]) && (n[4] > c[4]) ) ||
      ( (p[4] < c[4]) && (n[4] < c[4]) ) ) {
        print curr
}
{prev = curr; curr = $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:29.200000, 0.35
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:33.800000, 0.35
```

p = previous, c = current, n = next.

Comment: Glad this solves the problem, but could help the op rephrase the question?

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton it helped.

Comment: @sjsam which part?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > test.awk
t[1]==1 && p[1]>12 && $1>12 && ((t[4]>p[4] && t[4]>$4) || (t[4]<p[4] && t[4]<$4)) {
  print t[0]
} 
{
  p[1]=t[1];t[1]=$1;
  p[0]=t[0];t[0]=$0;
  p[4]=t[4];t[4]=$4;
}


$ awk -f test.awk test.in
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:29.200000, 0.35
  1 06-Jul-16 00:04:33.800000, 0.35
```

Answer (score 0):

This only reads the file once:

```
$1 == 1 {
    line[1] = $0;
    value[1] = $NF;
    next;
}
$1 > 12 {
    if (line[1] && line[0]) {
        if ((value[0] > value[1] && $NF > value[1]) || (value[0] < value[1] && $NF < value[1])) {
            print line[1];
            line[1] = "";
        }
    }
    line[0] = $0;
    value[0] = $NF;
    next;
}
{
    line[0] = "";
}
```

Comment: Did you notice this: - - _previous line and next line - - fourth columns both bigger or both lower_

Comment: Yes, the fourth also being the last in this case, hence value = $NF.